# Google script : Cross matching of Column and row from spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am beginner in scripting and am currently trying to complete an auto email sending system on google script, that sends email based on the number given by Spreadsheet (Calculation of days left until specified sending day).

By referencing the number (day left) from spreadsheet, I could managed to specify the column by matching the number held by the column and the one I specified. (in this case was "7").

After that, I wanted to get the number of row or data from the column I specified earlier by first referencing the column number from earlier and using "for" to look through the rows in the column to find desirable data. ("1" in this case)

I could managed to work it out, but **it processes super slow...**
I have been looking for the solution for while already but could not figure out the way.

So it would be very grateful if you share me any ideas for solutions.
The script I attempt is below.

```
    function AutoSend() {     
      // Get the spreadsheet
      var book = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

      // Get cal      
      var Calsheet = book.getSheetByName("cal");

      //=========================================================//       
      // Get data range that contains data     
      var CaldatRange = Calsheet.getDataRange();

      //=========================================================//     
      // Get the row number of Cal to process      
      var CalnumRows = CaldatRange.getNumRows();

      // Get the column number of Cal to process     
      var CalnumCols = CaldatRange.getNumColumns();

      //=========================================================//        
      // Get the number of column to start to process   
      var Cstart = Calsheet.getRange(6, 5).getValue();

     //=========================================================//       

var coldata  = [];

var rowdata  = [];

for (var j = Cstart;j <= CalnumCols;j++){

var colnumfind = Calsheet.getRange(6, j).getColumn();

var status     = Calsheet.getRange(3, j).getValue();

var dayLeft    = Calsheet.getRange(4, j).getValue();

var Sdate      = Calsheet.getRange(5, j).getValue(); 

    if(dayLeft == "7" && status == "未送信")
    {
      Browser.msgBox("確認",colnumfind, Browser.Buttons.OK);
      coldata = colnumfind;
      for (var i = 6; i <= CalnumRows; i++)
      {
        var sendOK     = Calsheet.getRange(i,coldata).getValue();
        var rownumfind = Calsheet.getRange(i, coldata).getRow();

        if(sendOK == "1")
        {
          rowdata   = rownumfind;
          var email = Calsheet.getRange(rowdata,3).getValue();
          Browser.msgBox("確認","found it : Row " + rowdata +", Column "+ coldata + " " + email, Browser.Buttons.OK); 
          //PUT SEND EMAIL FUNCTION
        }

      }
      Calsheet.getRange(3,coldata).setValue("送信済");
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: To be clear, you define a column in C3 that you get. You want to find out how many rows that column has and extract something? In the current setup you are doing a lot of calls to getValue. What is your ultimate goal? I feel this can be achieved easier.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
The ultimate goal is to create auto mailing using gmail.

We open frequent events so decided to use google form to collect application and store them in spreadsheet.

Comment: And we send them email automatically, 7 days in advance to remind them.

so the coding I am having problem with is this reminder system based on how many days left. 

For some reason I managed to solved the issue I had and now its reading the second "for", but it takes long time to process this simple method...
How can I post the updated script on here??

Comment: Found edit :)
I updated my script so please take a look, it does it job but as you mentioned, too many "getValue" and it processes super slow...
Are there any alternatives to make this process more simple??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a start use CaldatRange.getValues(), here is an example:

```
var values = CaldatRange.getValues();

for (var j = Cstart-1;j < CalnumCols;j++){
var status     = values[2][j];
var dayLeft    = values[3][j];
var Sdate      = values[4][j]; 
var colnumfind = j+1;
```

You can also change these:

```
var sendOK     = values[i-1,coldata]
var rownumfind = i;

var email = values[i-1,2];
```

This will eliminate all your getValue calls.

Comment: Thank you for your solution utphx!
This dramatically cut down the process time!
However, I got another issue with detecting desirable row. 

Until `if(dayLeft == "7" && status == "未送信")`
it reads correct column (76th in this case which contains "7") but when it reads
`var sendOK = values[i-1,coldata]`
 it gives me wrong column (it was 72nd), so it doesn't read the row it supposed to read.

what would be the issue here??

Comment: is it 1 row off?  then try this: for (var i = 5; i <= CalnumRows; i++)